# ImageMagick convert adds a Gray diagonal line during convert

Tags: imagemagick

Trying to convert a PDF into png using ImageMagick convert on Windows and the resulting image is including multiple Grey diagonal lines. Not sure whats forcing IM to add these. Tried multiple parameters.

```
c:\\>ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\convert +antialias -trim  -density 400 pdf\%1 img\Out-%%02d.png
```

[image: what i want]

The original PDF page does not have these diagonal lines in grey bands. Earlier I had such lines even in the colored boxes, could remove them using +antialias

Below is how the original PDF page looks like

[image]

Comment: Ehm... the two images are the same!

Comment: Seems some issue with my uploaded image. Here is the link https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rnn2.png

Comment: the differences are barely invisible

Comment: Post a link to your original PDF. All you show is a PNG. Your upload to that server has changed your PDF to a PNG. We need to see the actual PDF. It could be an issue with the version of your Ghostscript delegate that Imagemagick uses. Please check the version and upgrade to the most current one. Note that it is 9.25. Avoid 9.22, which has had bug complaints. The -trim should come after you read the PDF and should be followed with +repage. The +antialias probably does nothing in that command.